# Is it possible to add Java support to Netbeans+PHP installed package?

Tags: java, php, netbeans

under Ubuntu I have installed Netbeans with PHP and HTML Js support.

What's the best way to add also Java support?

Should I download from  https://netbeans.org/downloads/ 
the package under Java SE and install over? Or better the "all" package?
Or some other better approach?
Any experience with this situation?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for bothering, I found out myself. Very simple: 
You can add or remove packs later using the IDE's Plugin Manager (Tools | Plugins).

Browsing Available Plugins, sort by category, I can find anything I need.

Comment: Which packs should be added for general Java development? 

ie if i'm downloading an open source Java package like Netbeans, which plugins do I need?

Answer (score 3):

1. install full JDK
2. **either edit:** <netbeans-IDE-installation>/etc/netbeans.conf

   1. unmark 'netbeans_jdkhome'
   2. link to JDK location e.g. */usr/local/share/java/jdk1.6.0_07/*
3. **or use:** '--jdkhome' command-line option e.g. *./bin/netbeans --jdkhome /usr/local/share/java/jdk1.6.0_07/*

Please check: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre

Answer (score -1):

If you're confused which java plugin to install, you can download Netbeans java bundle and install. The installation will combine both features (PHP, Java). Tested with Netbeans 8.2.

And then :
- Install JDK if you haven't.
- open netbeans conf file at ./etc/netbeans.conf, set "netbeans_jdkhome" to your jdk instalation.

Good luck.